# Four numbers drawn from 1 to 100000 randomly, the same number may be chosen more than once.

Tags: combinatorics

Four numbers drawn from 1 to 100000 randomly, the same number may be chosen more than once. Determine probability the last digit from multiplying that four numbers is 1 or 9.
I have tried with many cases with it but it come a big number on combination.

Comment: Good question mate; give me some time.

Comment: Hint: reduce the range to $0-9$, the answer will be the same.

Comment: You get some amazing patterns when you write out last digits of x by 2, 3 and 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we may assume we only draw numbers from the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$. This is the case because only the last digit of the number we picked matters. Let us call the random numbers $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. If one of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ is even or divisible by $5$, then $ABCD$ is as well and then it will not end in a $1$ or $9$. The probability that $ A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are all coprime to $10$ is $(\frac25)^4$ (we can only pick $1$, $3$, $7$, $9$). We can now show that the last digit of $AB$ takes these values $1$, $3$, $7$, $9$ with equal probability and that the same holds for $ABC$ and $ABCD$. In half of the cases the last digit will be $1$ or $9$. This yields a final answer of 
$$
\left(\frac25\right)^4 \cdot \frac12 = 0.0128.
$$

**Edit:** Consider the multiplication table of $1$, $3$, $7$ and $9$ (we consider last digits only):
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times & 1 & 3 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline
1 & {\color{green}1} & 3 & 7 & {\color{green}9} \\
3 & 3 & {\color{green}9} & {\color{green}1} & 7 \\
7 & 7 & {\color{green}1} & {\color{green}9} & 3 \\
9 & {\color{green}9} & 7 & 3 & {\color{green}1}
\end{array}
$$
Exactly half of the entries of this table is a $1$ or a $9$, so if the last digits of $X$ and $Y$ are independently equidistributed on $\{1,3,7,9\}$ then so is the last digit of $XY$.

Comment: why in half of the cases the last digit will be 1 or 9 ?

Comment: I expanded my answer to explain this some more.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you multiply every number from 1 - 9 by every number from 1 - 9, and write down the last digit, you get this:

```
  │ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
──┼──────────────────
1 │ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 │ 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8
3 │ 3 6 9 2 5 8 3 6 9
4 │ 4 8 2 6 0 4 8 2 6
5 │ 5 0 5 0 5 0 5 0 5
6 │ 6 2 8 4 0 6 2 8 4
7 │ 7 4 1 8 5 2 9 6 3
8 │ 8 6 4 2 0 8 6 4 2
9 │ 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Then every number in that grid by the numbers from 0-9 again:

```
│ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     Patterns below
├──────────────────     ───────────────
│ 1 4 9 6 5 6 9 4 1     <-- Square numbers
│ 2 8 8 2 0 2 8 8 2     <-- Look at row 8
│ 3 2 7 8 5 8 7 2 3
│ 4 6 6 4 0 4 6 6 4     <-- Look at row 6
│ 5 0 5 0 5 0 5 0 5
│ 6 4 4 6 0 6 4 4 6     <-- Look at row 4
│ 7 8 3 2 5 2 3 8 7
│ 8 2 2 8 0 8 2 2 8     <-- Look at row 2
│ 9 6 1 4 5 4 1 6 9     <-- 10 subtract first row
```

Anyway, these grids both have four 1s and four 9s. I expect it will be the same for multiplying 4 numbers. This should help you solve your problem.

Comment: We seem to be keen about answering this question; have a look at my answer to see whether it gives you any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've not solved the question completely; I'm in the process of it, and encourage fellow answerers and the OP to take a look at the list below which includes findings relatable to the question, and carry on the solution from there. I'll regularly update it as I find more and more details/ the answer itself...

- Even if one of the four numbers is an even number, it won't end in a 1 or 9.
- Even if one of the four numbers ends in a five, it won't end in a 1 or 9.
- If all four numbers end in the same digit, you'll be getting 1 or 9 only in case of all numbers ending in 1 or 9.
- 1,1,1,9 ; 9,9,9,1 ; 3,3,3,7 ; 7,7,7,3 : End in 1 or 9. (Note: order can vary; include in P&C)
- One general observation: {a,a,b,b}, where $a,b \in(1,3,7,9)$ , will always end in a 1 or a 9. (again, order may vary, but is irrelevant)